# Why deploy-tool in my WAS Liberty local installation is blocked?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I want to know because page of deploy tool in my local installation of admin center is blocked (I've installed WAS Liberty in my PC)

I get this message:

*Cannot access host or deploy rules information on the server*

[image]

This is my server.xml

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>collectiveController-1.0</feature>
        <feature>collectiveMember-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>   

    <!-- This template enables security. To get the full use of all the capabilities, a keystore and user registry are required. -->

    <!-- For the keystore, default keys are generated and stored in a keystore. To provide the keystore password, generate an 
         encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it below in the password attribute of the keyStore element. 
         Then uncomment the keyStore element. -->
    <!--
    <keyStore password=""/> 
    -->

    <!--For a user registry configuration, configure your user registry. For example, configure a basic user registry using the
        basicRegistry element. Specify your own user name below in the name attribute of the user element. For the password, 
        generate an encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it in the password attribute of the user element. 
        Then uncomment the user element. -->
    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm"> 
        <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  -->
        <user name="admin" password="adminpwd"/>
    </basicRegistry>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9444" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <keyStore location="${server.output.dir}/resources/security/liberty.jks" password="adminadmin"/>
    <administrator-role>
        <user>admin</user>
    </administrator-role>

    <remoteFileAccess>
       <writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir>
    </remoteFileAccess>

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <webApplication id="prueba" location="prueba.war" name="prueba"/>
</server>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be sure from the information provided, but my guess is that you manually added the collectiveController-1.0 feature, but didn't actually create the collective (which you would by running the 'collective create {serverName}' command from wlp/bin.  Since the deploy tool is only applicable on a collective controller, if it's not configured properly it will not work.

You can find detailed instructions for creating a collective here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_configure_collective.html

Comment: I tried to follow that tutorial but I get error when I triedo execue command: collective join myMember .... I get an error message that said me: "port 9443 is not available" (as it was ocuped for another process). With resmon (a tool of Windows) I can see that when execue command  javaw.exe process used port 9443. It's as if they had a crashed...Well..I'm stopped...

Comment: That error message sounds like the collective controller is not running when you're trying to join your member to it, however that would not be the cause of the issue you're seeing regarding the Deploy tool in Admin Center since you don't need any members in order to use the Deploy tool, just a configured controller which would be the result of completing Step 1 in the above link.

Comment: I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=zsMIe1gvkjc&vq=hd1080) of IBM's page. There indicates that I should create a member...Thus, I only should create a controller?

Comment: You can create as many members are you'd like/need; my point was simply that you don't need any to use the deploy tool.  The issue seems to be that the controller was not set up correctly.  Step 1e states "Verify that the collective controller server started correctly and is ready to receive members." by checking the log for "CWWKX9003I".  My guess is that you won't see that in your log because the controller is not configured properly as I don't see all the keystores in your sever.xml that the collective create command creates (nor alternatively an <include file /> that would import them)

Comment: As a follow up, note that per the instructions you need to either set --createConfigFile when doing the collective create and include the file in your server.xml, or copy and paste the output of the collective create into your server.xml; that seems to be missing from what you pasted in your post.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. I have problems with ${server.config.dir} variable. This variable should have value of controller folder path but It has value of path server. How I can solve that? If I use complete path instead of variable, then I have another error message: File collective.uuid haven't found in location